# Request with -curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I would like to run a curl command to request data from an API, but I'm not sure of how to do it. To transform curl request into ruby code, I'm using [curl to ruby](https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/), which is great by the way.

Following the doc API, I have this :

Step 1 (Get your token) :

```
curl -X POST https://api.monkey-locky.com/login_check -d _username={usr}
-d _password={pwd}
```

I have translated this by :

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.monkey-locky.com/login_check")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.set_form_data(
  "_password" => "my_secret_pass",
  "_username" => "my@mail.co",
)

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

print response.body
```

This request give me an Token to use the API.

Step 2 (Verify if the token is working) :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]" https://api.monkeylocky.com/bookings
```

I have translated this by :

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.monkeylocky.com/bookings")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer [TOKEN]"

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

But this script is rendering an error like this :

> `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to
>   api.monkeylocky.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided,
>   or not known) (SocketError)

I'm not very comfortable with CURL, I'm just starting to use these request. So I'm not sure of what I'm doing right now. Any suggestion about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the first request to `https://api.monkey-locky.com` but the URL in the second request is `https://api.monkeylocky.com` (no dash)

Comment: That was a stupid error, thanks a lot for your time @dlmb !!